# Laravel 5.1 : argument or values not readable by Query Builder

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5.1, query-builder

This is my route.php

```
Route::get('tempitems/{tempId}/add/{q?}', 
['uses' => 'ItemTemplateController@addItems', 'as' => 'tempitems.add']);
```

This is the `addItems` method

```
public function addItems(Request $request, $tempId)
{
 echo ($tempId) // 1 st echo

 $temp = DB::table('auto_items')
            ->join('items', 'auto_items.item_id', '=', 'items.id')
            ->select(
                'items.name',
                'auto_items.qty'
                )
            ->where('auto_items.template_id', '=' , $tempId)
            ->tosql();

  dd($temp);

  echo $tempId; // 2nd echo

  return view('template_items.add_items', [
      'active'    => $this->active,
      'items'     => $items,
      'template'  => $template,
      'page'      => $page,
      'success'   => $success,
      'tempItems' => $tempItems
    ]);  
}
```

The query builder cannot read the `$tempId` when I acces `localhost:8000/tempitems/1/add`

```
1st echo => return 1
dd return => 
"select `items`.`name`, `auto_items`.`qty` from `auto_items` inner join `items` on 
`auto_items`.`item_id` = `items`.`id` where `auto_items`.`template_id` = ?"

2nd echo returned 1
```

I know that the QueryBuilder uses get() to return rows because it returned a zero array / [ ]; that's why I'm using `toSql()`. However, `$tempId` cannot be read by the QueryBuilder.

EDIT : before edit i am using

```
->where('auto_items.template_id', '=' , 1)
```

above code still returned '?'

```
->where('auto_items.template_id', '=' , $tempId)
```

and this is also returned '?'

Comment: I really don't see the problem, you don't use `$tempId` in your query and `$tempId` has the same value through the function. So, what is the problem?

Comment: @Jerodev hi thanks for reply, the problem is the query builder returned $tempId as '?' but the echo before and after works perfect

Comment: @kotkoth - the ? is just a placeholder, as Laravel uses prepared statements. It doesn't mean this value is used in your query.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make sure that variable that you inserted processed into query or not, you better use `DB::getQueryLog()`, it's still show `?` in query but show your variable in `bindings`

```
    DB::enableQueryLog();
    $temp = DB::table('tabel')
        ->where('id', '=' , 1)
        ->get();
    return json_encode(DB::getQueryLog());
```

sample result :

```
    [{"query":"select * from `age` where `id` = ?","bindings":[1],"time":0.19}]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot ! i knew it it must be some kind of mistake, and after all it was my code fault .